# Walkthrough Illumina Genotyping

Tags: dna-sequencing, genomics, microarray, methods

I would love help outlining a basic walkthrough of the wet-lab techniques for processing blood samples from patients, all the way to loading a BeadChip, to the part just before Next Generation Sequencing takes place. Here is my basic understanding so far, that I am not 100% certain is accurate. I am not a biologist - I just communicate with them, so I do not need any confusing assay names/specifications that are important only for wet lab biologists.

```
Steps:
1. Collect blood from patient. 
2. Purify DNA by isolating DNA 
            (Procedure (?): lyse/sonicate, bind using ethanol, centrifuge, 
            wash with buffer, centrifuge again, rinse with water, centrifuge 
            again)
3. Cut DNA into 100-150 bp read fragments 
            (Procedure (?): with restriction enzymes? how do you determine 
            read length with restriction enzymes?)
4. Separate double stranded reads into single stranded reads 
            (Procedure (?): denature with heat) 
5. Amplify reads via PCR, leaving you with many single stranded reads
6. Disperse sample evenly into all cells on a BeadChip. The BeadChip 
      contains bountiful DNA polymerase and fluorescently tagged single nucleotides. 
7. Submit the BeadChip to the Next Generation Sequencer for processing.
8. You end up with a BUNCH of images which you can transcribe into sequences 
      based on the color illuminated in each photo capture, in each position 
      on the BeadChip.
```

Here's what doesn't make sense to me:
Step 6. You either have to only put one PCR read product in each cell at a time - which would take FOREVER, if you wanted to sequence someone's whole genome... Or you have more than one light going off per *cell*, per BeadChip, in each photo. If the latter is the case (which it would have to be for high throughput wet lab experiments), how do you determine between photo captures *of a given cell in a BeadChip* that the nucleotide going off in photo 2 is a part of fragment n or n+k?

Does this make sense? Basically, how are BeadChips loaded with sample reads for NGS genotyping? I know that reads are "anchored", but are they anchored in each cell of the BeadChip? This is the only way this makes sense to me.

Thanks for any insights!

Comment: Genotyping and Next Gen Sequencing are two entirely different applications.  If you are using BeadChips, you are genoptying.

Comment: The BeadChip is literally a silica chip that holds beads in an array. Each bead contains many copies of a specific oligonucleotide that bind and capture genomic DNA fragments.

Comment: @swbarnes2, isn't the input of NGS a beadchip? What is the difference between sequencing and genotyping? NGS is a sequencing technology that gives you the nucleotide sequence of sample DNA. Is this not genotyping?

Comment: Nope. NGS puts prepared DNA fragments on a flow cell, and gives you millions of short reads.  Genotyping gives you a single letter at a single pre-determined position, or in this case, the single base at a few million chosen locations.  BeadArray technology is genotyping, not sequencing.